# Finding the frequency difference elements in a list

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, hashmap

Actually I am trying to solve this problem [hackerrank Missing Numbers](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/missing-numbers)

Allow me to add some description to it, actually there are two list of numbers, almost same, but for the fact some are missing in the first list, so second list has all the numbers intact but the first one has some of them missing we just have to print the missing numbers from the first list.

Problem Statement

Numeros, the Artist, had two lists A and B, such that B was a permutation of A. Numeros was very proud of these lists. Unfortunately, while transporting them from one exhibition to another, some numbers from A got left out. Can you find the numbers missing?

Notes

If a number occurs multiple times in the lists, you must ensure that the frequency of that number in both lists is the same. If that is not the case, then it is also a missing number.

You have to print all the missing numbers in ascending order.

Print each missing number once, even if it is missing multiple times.

The difference between maximum and minimum number in B is less than or equal to 100.

Input Format 
There will be four lines of input:

```
n - the size of the first list 
This is followed by n space-separated integers that make up the first list. 
m - the size of the second list 
This is followed by m space-separated integers that make up the second list.
```

Output Format 
Output the missing numbers in ascending order:-

Constraints

```
1≤n,m≤1000010 
1≤x≤10000,x∈B 
Xmax−Xmin<101
```

Sample Input

```
10
203 204 205 206 207 208 203 204 205 206
13
203 204 204 205 206 207 205 208 203 206 205 206 204
```

Sample Output

```
204 205 206
```

I wrote the code :-

Here it is :-

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        Map<Integer, Integer> mA = new HashMap<>(n);
        int curr = 0;
        while(n--> 0){// Creating the first map having number & its frequency
            curr = scan.nextInt();
            if(mA.containsKey(curr)){
                Integer prev = mA.get(curr);
                mA.put(curr, prev + 1);
            }else{
                mA.put(curr, 1);
            }
        }

        int n1 = scan.nextInt();
        Map<Integer, Integer> mB = new HashMap<>(n1);
        while(n1--> 0){// Creating the second map having number & its frequency
            curr = scan.nextInt();
            if(mB.containsKey(curr)){
                Integer prev = mB.get(curr);
                mB.put(curr, prev + 1);
            }else{
                mB.put(curr, 1);
            }   
        }

            List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();

            //Problem I think is this part somewhere I am not doing it correct in this loop
            for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : mB.entrySet()){
                Integer k = entry.getKey();
                Integer v = entry.getValue();
                if(!mA.containsKey(k)){
                   l.add(k);
                }else if(mA.get(k) != v){
                    l.add(k);
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(l);
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(l));

           for(Integer i : l){
               System.out.print(i + " ");
           }
        }
}
```

*The problem I think is in the for loop where I am comparing the entries in the two maps. I think I am not doing it right way!!*
 **Because its printing a number which has same frequency count in both the maps.**

Comment: What is your problem? your output is not correct?

Comment: Yes its printing a number which has same frequency count in both the maps.

Comment: Strangely enough, I don't see any problem with your code. Do you have the input for which there is a problem?

Comment: Yeah I have and I want to share but its a big list of numbers how to pass it to everyone else? https://hr-testcases.s3.amazonaws.com/458/input02.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1430242905&Signature=tXN1BTLGpxPvpTkBat6ayxQs%2B1w%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain

Comment: Correct output would be https://hr-testcases.s3.amazonaws.com/458/output02.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1430245666&Signature=ZZ2jxtQfYWyEwsfOqUv6YoaQx18%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain

Comment: Are you able to access these links!!

Comment: @JohnDoe update my answer, take a look :)

Comment: @Jone Doe, if you don't have a very large lists,     -create a mapList1<number,count> , create a mapList2<number, count> (same method different list) --- you are doing that already, than convert a pair<number, freq>  "204-3", "205-2" -- strings by iterating over it -- create a setList1<String> and setList2<String> ,  call intersection.. much easier..  get the results/parse and print .. let the set do the filtering for you.

Comment: Yes this also is a good approach, however what I have seen that this heavy reliance on Collection framework tends to take too much time and at times timeout happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : mB.entrySet()){
    Integer k = entry.getKey();
    Integer v = entry.getValue();
    if(!mA.containsKey(k)){
        l.add(k);
    }else if(mA.get(k).intValue() != v.intValue()){//This is the problem
        l.add(k);
    }
}
```

Because, previously you are comparing two **Integer objects** not two `int` values (for small value of integer, it all mapped to same object, but for larger one, Java create new object when doing auto boxing).

This problem, actually only need one Map, and you can find this more convenience if you use a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) instead of HashMap.

Notice that `Xmax - Xmin < 101`, so we can even use an array `data[101]` to store the numbers, for further improvement.

Comment: So the only problem was this Integer objects and not any other thing?? How did you ascertained this so quickly I bet I would have taken days to figure this out on my own, Thanks a lot. Please share more about this thing if possible.

Comment: @JohnDoe you can have different approach as I suggested, but for your current approach, this is the problem :)

Comment: Sure Sure I am still figuring things out and the way I do things I know,  is not very elegant, but I am willing to work on the ways you have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with arrays:

```
int[] a = new int[n];
int[] b = new int[m];
// read into a and b
int[] freqs = new int[10001];

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    freqs[b[i]]++;
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    freqs[a[i]]--;
}
for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++)
{
    if (freqs[i] > 0) System.out.println(i + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  void printmissing(HashMap<Integer, Integer> firstset,HashMap<Integer, Integer> secondset){
    Set<Integer> keys=secondset.keySet();
    for(Integer k:keys){
        secondset.put(k, secondset.get(k)-firstset.get(k));
    }
    for(Integer k:keys){
        if(secondset.get(k)>0)
            System.out.print(" "+k);
    }
```

Add the integer values in the LinkedHashMap in the main method  and call the above method to display the missing number in order wise

```
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> firstset=new LinkedHashMap<>();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer>  secondset=new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`

```
public class Abce{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> A = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        A.add(1);
        A.add(1);
        A.add(1);
        A.add(2);
        A.add(1);

        ArrayList<Integer> B = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        B.add(1);
        B.add(1);
        B.add(2);
        B.add(1);

        //Find and remove
        for (Integer integer : B) {
            if (A.contains(integer)) {
                A.remove(integer);
            }

        }

        //Print the remaining items
        for (Integer integer : A) {
            System.out.println(integer);
        }

    }
}`
```

Comment: I need to have the frequency consideration also.

Comment: In above if as a result you will get 1 . so frequency has been considered.In List A having 1 integer 4 times while in List B having 1 integer only 3 times.Hence result is 1 as the remaining is removed.Actually As a result I am showing missing number is 1 because frequency is not matching.